# Extracting children as lines

Tags: csv, xslt

I have a XML file which I am trying to convert to a csv.
I have done similar things in the past already, but the issue this time is that the columns of my CSV contain the parents in the XML. This leads to issues.

Given the following sample XML structure :

```
<...>
    <thing name="Type1">
        <...>
            <category name="cat1">
                <value>12.65456</value>
            </category>
            <category name="cat2">
                <value>4.56785</value>
            </category>
            <category name="cat3">
                <value>1.3658</value>
            </category>                        
        </...>
    </thing>
    <thing name="Type2">
        <...>
            <category name="cat1">
                <value>xx.xxxxx</value>
            </category>
            <category name="cat2">
                <value>xx.xxxxx</value>
            </category>
            <category name="cat3">
                <value>xx.xxxxx</value>
            </category>    
            <category name="cat4">
                <value>xx.xxxx</value>
            </category>                        
        </...>
    </thing> 
    <thing name="Type3">
        <...>
            <category name="cat1">
                <value>xx.xxxxx</value>
            </category>
            <category name="cat2">
                <value>xx.xxxxx</value>
            </category>   
            <category name="cat4">
                <value>xx.xxxx</value>
            </category>                        
        </...>
    </thing>    
</...>
```

Please do note that in the XML document:

- All types do not hold each category
- All types list categories in the same order

I would like to get the following output csv file

```
        Type1       Type2       Type3   ....
cat1    12.65456    xx.xxxx     xx.xxxx
cat2    4.56785     xx.xxxx     xx.xxxx
cat3    1.3658      xx.xxxx     
cat4                xx.xxxx     xx.xxxx
....    .....       .......     .......
```

(Note that for readability I have added tabs, but I use commas in the transformations. This shouldn't matter).

At first, I have tried to go through each thing as such :

```
  <xsl:template match=".../thing">
      <xsl:for-each select="category">

        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@name='cat1'">
              ...
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@name='cat2'">
              ...
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

But the issue here is that the output will have its lines scrambled:

`12.65456    xx.xxxx     xx.xxxx 4.56785     xx.xxxx     xx.xxxx ....`

I have also tried to directly hit the categories

```
<xsl:template match=".../thing/category[cat1]">
  ....
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match=".../thing/category[cat2]">
  ....
</xsl:template>
....
```

But due to the way XSLT goes through the tree I also cannot ensure that the order of the output will be correct.

Finally, I have been looking into saving the "growing" results into variables but it turns out that variables cannot be overriden in XSLT.

SO my question is : Is there a way to run through the tree such that I get the desired output ?

Any lead would be much appreciated :).

Thanks, 
Julien

Comment: Your example is confusing. Is your input a regular table - i.e. does every `thing` have the same `category` nodes (and in the same order), as would seem from your output example? Or is it a sparse array, as shown in your input example (i.e. there is no `cat4` value for `Type1`)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k. Actually, a bit of both, which is why I created the table that way. All categories are listed in the same order, but not all categories are present in each type. I will update my question

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: Do you mean which version? I can use both 1.0 and 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us have a workable input example:

**XML**

```
<root>
  <thing name="Type1">
    <wrapper>
      <category name="cat1">
        <value>1.10</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat2">
        <value>1.20</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat3">
        <value>1.30</value>
      </category>
    </wrapper>
  </thing>
  <thing name="Type2">
    <wrapper>
      <category name="cat1">
        <value>2.10</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat2">
        <value>2.20</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat3">
        <value>2.30</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat4">
        <value>2.40</value>
      </category>
    </wrapper>
  </thing>
  <thing name="Type3">
    <wrapper>
      <category name="cat1">
        <value>3.10</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat2">
        <value>3.20</value>
      </category>
      <category name="cat4">
        <value>3.40</value>
      </category>
    </wrapper>
  </thing>
</root>
```

Now, to make a long story short, you want to create a row for every distinct value of `category/@name` and a data cell for every `thing`.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="thing"/>
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>Category&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$columns/@name" separator="&#9;"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     <!-- data -->
   <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(thing/wrapper/category/@name)">
        <xsl:variable name="cat" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$cat"/>
        <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
            <xsl:value-of select="wrapper/category[@name=$cat]/value" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
Category  Type1     Type2     Type3
cat1      1.10      2.10      3.10
cat2      1.20      2.20      3.20
cat3      1.30      2.30      
cat4                2.40      3.40
```

---

This could be made a bit more efficient by using a **key** to fetch the value of each data cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It took me a couple days to accept the answer because I realized later that xslt 2.0 wasn't supported in the application so I had to translate it back. I wasnt aware that a whole tree could be saved as a variable. That was an eye opener. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="thisRoot" select="."/>
    <!-- Title line -->
    <!-- Empty title for categories -->
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <!-- Type names -->
    <xsl:variable name="types" select="thing/@name"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($types, '&#x9;')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <!-- A line for each category -->
    <xsl:variable name="categories" select="distinct-values(//category/@name)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$categories">
      <!-- The current category -->
      <xsl:variable name="thisCateg" select="."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
      <!-- Loop for each type in this row -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$types">
        <xsl:variable name="thisType" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select=
          "$thisRoot/thing[@name = $thisType]//category[@name = $thisCateg]/value"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
          <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note that it is required to store the current object (`.`) in a variable
for future reference, because the current assignment of the current object
changes in various places.

Types and categories are read from the input file, without hard-coding
them in the XSLT script.

For your data (slightly changed) I got the following result:

```
    Type1   Type2   Type3
cat1    12.65456    xx.xxxx1    yy.xxxx1
cat2    4.56785 xx.xxxx2    yy.xxxx2
cat3    1.3658  xx.xxxx3    yy.xxxx3
cat4        xx.xxx4 xx.xxx4
```

Comment: But he said expressly: "Note that for readability I have added tabs, but I use commas in the transformations.*" So your padding with spaces makes no sense.

Comment: It seems that initially I read "too fast" and missed the remark concerning spaces addded for readability. Now I changed the solution to truly *TAB* separated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help as well. I decided to go for @michael.hor257k's solution because it is slightly more concise.